# Stringing together a series of foreign keys to return a table value in Django

Tags: python, django

How do I select the ctype knowing the user?

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CompanyType(models.Model):
    ctype = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    companytype = models.ForeignKey(CompanyType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I know I can do it this way, but is there a way to chain it altogether in one line?

```
def getcompanytype(request):
    user_id = request.user.id
    company_id = Profile.objects.get(user_id__exact=user_id).company_id
    companytype_id = Company.objects.get(id=company_id).companytype_id
    companytype = CompanyType.objects.get(id=companytype_id).ctype
    return(companytype)
```

essentially I want this SQL statement:

```
SELECT
ct.ctype
From auth_user u
left outer join Profile p
on p.user_id = u.id
left outer join Company c
on p.company_id = c.id
left outer join CompanyType ct
on ct.id = c.companytype_id
where u.id = 1 # actually current user ID, not hardcoded "1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this by following the reverse relationships of the ForeignKeys in a `filter` or `get` call, joining the different relations together with double underscores:

```
CompanyType.objects.get(company__profile__user__id__exact=user_id).ctype
```

Although I'd suggest you try that out in a Django shell and make sure that the reverse relationships are named how you'd expect! (For example, `CompanyType` will have a `company_set` attribute that gives all the companies with a particular `CompanyType`; the `_set` shouldn't be included when you do filter queries.)

Comment: thanks!  Didn't work but I fiddled around with it and figured this out:  CompanyType.objects.get(company__profile__user__id__exact=user_id).ctype  If you agree that's good (it worked for me) then perhaps you can edit your answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: Yup, that makes sense, will edit. (EDIT: And changed!)